# How to consume a java rest to render nv3d candlestick chart with Angular?

Tags: java, angular, rest, charts, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to use nvd3d candlestick chart with Angular, but I'm not getting to render it when using a rest service built in Java.

How to consume a java rest to render nv3d candlestick chart with Angular?

My rest is returning this:

`[{"id":450,"vwap":3821.62,"faixa":69.48,"open":3858.7,"high":3863.29,"low":3793.81,"close":3795.54,"date":19338}]`

The component expected this:

`[{values:[{"id":450,"vwap":3821.62,"faixa":69.48,"open":3858.7,"high":3863.29,"low":3793.81,"close":3795.54,"date":19338}]}]`

My Angular code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Provider, SkipSelf, Optional, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { HttpInterceptorService, RESTService } from '@covalent/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';


export interface IDolFutDiario {
id: number;
  date: number;
  open: number;
  high: number;
  low: number;
  close: number;
  vwap: number;
  faixa: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class DolfudiarioService extends RESTService<IDolFutDiario>{

  constructor(private _http: HttpInterceptorService) {
    super(_http, {
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080', 
      path: '',
    });
  }

  staticQuery(): Observable<IDolFutDiario[]> {

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/dolfutdiarios')
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }

  extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
 }  

 private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

My Java code:

```
@RestController
public class DolFutRestController {

    @Autowired
    DolFutDiarioService dolFutDiarioService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "dolfutdiarios", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<DolFutDiario>> list() {
        List<DolFutDiario> dolfutdiarios = dolFutDiarioService.listDolFutDiarios();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dolfutdiarios);
    }   
}
```

PS: When I put the second block of data  `[[values: .....` , it works.
However when I get from Java Service it does not. 
No errors returned as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to convert the block of data you get to the one you want. It's not going to work if you use the wrong format. The crux of the matter is in this method:

```
extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
}
```

There you can map your data to what you need; for example, if you want to wrap it in a values object, do it like so:

```
extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return [{ values: body }];
}
```

Also, try `console.log`'ing your code in different steps to see what you have and compare to what you need!